# Subversion over HTTP, which command results in the following requests?

Tags: svn, svnsync, mod-dav-svn

I'm currently debugging issues with a proprietary third party svn client that I don't have the source code to (I'm confident it operates around the standard `svn` command and the user-agent matches that). When being asked to analyze our repo it does the following 14 requests to our server

```
OPTIONS /svn/myrepo
OPTIONS /svn/myrepo
OPTIONS /svn/myrepo
PROPFIND /svn/myrepo/!svn/rvr/1
OPTIONS /svn/myrepo
PROPFIND /svn/myrepo
--------------------------------
OPTIONS /svn/myrepo
OPTIONS /svn/myrepo
OPTIONS /svn/myrepo
OPTIONS /svn/myrepo
OPTIONS /svn/myrepo
PROPFIND /svn/myrepo/!svn/rev/0
PROPFIND /svn/myrepo/!svn/rev/1
REPORT /svn/myrepo/!svn/rev/1
```

I believe I've identified the first six as a `svn info URL`, which makes sense.

However, I can't figure out which svn command causes the remaining 8 requests. The last `REPORT` asks for a `replay-report` and receives an `editor-report` (which contains the textdelta right away). If I do a regular `svn co URL` it asks for an `update-report` and receives an `update-report` (which doesn't contain the textdelta, but an `D:href` that causes a `GET`).

Does anyone know which `svn` (or possibly `svnsync`) command and arguments cause the requests? That would help a lot in narrowing down the issues locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable high-level operational logging, run your custom client and check the log. You should see events that correspond to the SVN client actions. Here are some examples:

- `checkout-or-export /MyProject/trunk r123 depth=infinity`
- `log (/path1,/path2,/path3) r21:87 discover-changed-paths revprops=()`
- `status /path r62 depth=infinity`

See [SVNBook](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/serverconfig/operational-logging/) for the complete list of the operational log events.

Comment: thanks! Looks like the eight requests are caused by `svnsync init` and `svnsync sync` (but the order is a little messed up). That's `rev-proplist` followed by `replay` in terms of operational log.